# Quicksort; Segmentation Fault, but can't find where?

Tags: c++

I made a quicksort algorithm as normal functions within main, then attempted to transfer it to a class (per what my instructor wanted). However, I am now getting a segmentation fault error, but I cannot figure out where it is occurring. Source code below; thanks.

main.cpp

```
#include "MergeSort.h"
#include "QuickSort.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

int main() {
    cout << "This is compiling.\n";
    int testArray[SIZE] = {5,3,9,2,1,3,8,1,7,9};
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << testArray[i];
    }
    QuickSort test(testArray, SIZE);
    int * result = test.getArray();

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << result[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

QuickSort.cpp

```
#include "QuickSort.h"
//constructor
QuickSort::QuickSort(const int anArray[], int aSize) {
    array_p = new int[aSize];
    size = aSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array_p[i] = anArray[i];

    quickSort(0, aSize - 1);
    return;
}
//destructor
QuickSort::~QuickSort() {
    delete [] array_p;
    return;
}
//accessor function for array
int * QuickSort::getArray() {
    return array_p;
}

//PRIV MEM FUNCTIONS
void QuickSort::quickSort(int start, int end)
{
    if (start == end)
        return;

    int pivot;
    pivot = partition(array_p, start, end);

    //quickSort everything before where pivot is now
    quickSort(start, pivot - 1);

    //quickSort everything after where pivot is now
    quickSort(pivot, end);

    return;
}
int QuickSort::partition(int a[], int start, int end)
{
    int first, last, pivot;
    pivot = end;
    first = start;
    last = end - 1; //minus one is because pivot is at last

    while (first < last) {
        if (a[first] > a[pivot] && a[last] < a[pivot]) {
            swap(a, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
        else {
            if (a[first] <= a[pivot])
                first++;
            if (a[last] >= a[pivot])
                last--;
        }
    }

    if (a[pivot] > a[first]) {
        swap(a, pivot, first + 1);
        return first + 1;
    }
    else {
        swap(a, pivot, first);
        return first;
    }

}
void QuickSort::swap(int a[], int indexOne, int indexTwo)
{
    int temp = a[indexOne];
    a[indexOne] = a[indexTwo];
    a[indexTwo] = temp;
    return;
}
```

I think it *might* be

```
quickSort(start, pivot - 1);
```

because once I comment it out, I do not get the error; however, I cannot figure out why.

Comment: A pivot might very well be the `start` index, and then `quickSort(start, pivot - 1)` would call `quickSort` with `start > end`.

Comment: I changed `if (start == end)` to `if (start >= end)` within the quickSort function, but this does not fix the error. Do you think there is something else I am missing, or am I misunderstanding your comment/is my logic not valid?

Comment: This might be a good opportunity for you to practice/learn [debugging small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you don't have a debugger to help you step through the code, I would start by printing some diagnostic messages. Perhaps something like `std::cout << "quickSort(" << start << ", " << end << ")\n";` at the start of your `quickSort` function, before checking if `start` equals `end`. Even if this does not tell you where the fault occurs, it should narrow down when it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `quickSort(pivot, end);` 
to 
`quickSort(pivot+1, end);`

and 
`if (start == end)` 
to `if (start >= end)`.

Your code will run just fine now.